# How to add a visible arrow on side of a navigation view?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I'm trying to add a small arrow on the side of a navigation view so to indicate that there is a drawer on the screen. Something like this:

**>**

And when you drag it the navigation view will come out. I tried many solutions, looked for it but all I could find were topics about burger icon and the arrow that appears on the top of the navigation view and that's not what I need . I need a sided arrow that is visible and linked with the navigation view.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which side do you want to put your arrow on? Should it be on the titlebar/Appbar or other places? Is it a button or just a icon that can be swiped?

Comment: On the right side of navigation drawer .. I tried to add an image view inside the navigation view and change gravity to end and margin to -10 - to make it visible - but when I run nothing happens .. All what I want is just to make the user knows that there is some arrow (>) on the side of the screen  and when you swipe it the navigation drawer becomes visible. That's all.

Comment: Normally, if you add your image(icon) into navigation drawer, the user will see nothing when the drawer is closed. Then it will only be visible when user swipes and try to open the drawer, isn't it?